# How to add dependencies to devices in kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm working with some kernel 2.6.37 drivers.

I have a LCD panel driver (like those panel drivers [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/video/omap2/displays/?v=2.6.37)), whose power supply control is implemented like one of those LED devices under LED class

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/leds/leds-lp5521.c?v=2.6.37

This has worked for a while, because if initialized in the correct sequence, LED devices can always come up before panel starts initializing.

However, I'm now trying to get suspend-to-ram to work now, and I really struggling to make LED and panel suspend/resume in the correct order. The panel is always suspended after power is off, which doesn't do anything good, and always wakes up before power is up, which is counter-productive, too.

I did some research and found that around 2.6.33 they introduced multi-threading to the power management and it seems like the only solution is to specify explicit parent-child relationship between the two.

This is really non-trivial, because the LED class driver isn't designed to be parent to anything. Worse, this power-control LED driver is implemented through I2C and is itself broken during suspend-to-ram. Even worse, the panel driver is child to omap-dss driver which is very platform-specific and I haven't the time to fully understand it, yet.

Or, just get rid of the ugly power supply driver disguised as an LED and rewrite it with real PM driver interface, which again I have no clue how to do it, yet, either.

This is already a hell of ugly hacks, so I feel very OK to make it as ugly as it takes to make suspend-to-ram work.

In this particular case, suspend/wake-up happens in the context of one and only on particular application program, so it's not very difficult to ask the application to redo panel wakeup in user space in the application, after LED power is back on and stable.

Any brilliant (or ugly) suggestions to make this work?

Comment: Regulator framework is your friend. However, you hit known issue in the Linux, there is no other relations between devices than parent-child. And sometimes it is tricky to implicit a such.